# Does an inexpensive screw terminal "expansion strip" exist?

Tags: wire-terminals, screw-terminal, bad-wiring

I've got a messy security panel that needs cleaning up badly, as I need to connect another PCB for remote access and can't get the wires to reliably stay in place:

[image]

If you look at the black, red, green, and yellow terminals, they already have three separate wire (pairs) connected!

So far, a terminal strip like this is the only solution I can come up with.  However, I'd have to add an additional bus bar across the terminals that need to share a signal, which just adds to the size of the bar needed and is a little inconvenient:

[image]

There's always Phoenix Contact terminal blocks like the following:

[image]

However, at over $10 each from Digikey, it's a pretty expensive (though elegant looking) solution.

I guess I'm looking for something like the following photochopped image?

[image]

Note that I'd like a bus bar that connects the columns of terminals...

Can anyone suggest other options?

Answer (score 3):

A Punchdown block would do nicely.

[image]

None of those wires seem high gauged, and some look like they were puled out of cat 5 anyway.

Other names for these are 110 Blocks, 66 Blocks, M-Blocks. They are used for telephone, voice (Cat 3) and data (cat 5/6) wiring. Also used in alarm system wiring.

Comment: Ah, I like that!

Comment: got a direct link?  I am fighting with digikey's website on this one...

Comment: No direct link, but you can get these retail at like Lowes or Home Depot in the cable/tv/phone section, or any telcom or video equipment store. Hell, you could flag down a verizon truck and ask them, they install them in homes for wiring. That specific one I found via google image search, can't vet the store http://www.frostelectric.com/index.jsp?path=product&part=299751&ds=dept&process=search&qdx=0&ID=,Voice...Data,Patch.Panels...Accessories

Comment: @Dave and avoid the ones marked "split block" or that come with "bridging clips". Those arn't connected in the middle. Most new ones don't use bridging clips, the entire row is connected across.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll definitely hit up a store or the local electronics shop.

Comment: Well, Home Depot and Radio Shack were a bust.  But once I found that these blocks are also called "66 Blocks", I checked Amazon again and found the exact one you posted an image of!  And I got the last one!  Can't wait to get this and see how it works.  :)

Comment: Oh, it also looks like you edited your post and actually included the other names for the block.  Thanks!

Comment: @dave yea, I wanted to be complete on the information. Mind posting a link to the amazon page?

Comment: Here it is: http://www.amazon.com/Hubbell-BLOCK-MODULAR-66B-6PR/dp/B002FYCCTG/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1375278112&sr=8-6&keywords=66+block.  Note that people who have purchased it also bought bridging clips... so I don't know if this particular model bridges already or not, but I'll update this question once I receive the block.

Comment: @Dave the also bought list also has a Split M 4 x 50 Block. The Split blocks require the bridging clips. The 6x12 block you got should not.

Answer (score 0):

This terminal block from Phoenix is only $1.07 under 10 CNT. You could get a few of these and a section of DIN rail.

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/3044076/277-2026-ND/2051190
[PDF for 3044076 Series](http://media.digikey.com/PDF/Data%20Sheets/Phoenix%20Contact%20PDFs/3044076.pdf)

It can also take from 26AWG to 12AWG. Most of your wires look to be 26AWG (or similar).

Dont forget the jumpers to jump the blocks together that you want to match.
[Example Terminal Block Jumper](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/3038930/277-3297-ND/2263802)

I am also a fan of Ferrules but they are definitely not required in a stationary one insert application.

The following is a link to a Ferrule Kit. There are many less expensive ones, this is just one i found quickly on digi.

[Example Ferrule Kit](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/9028710000/281-3050-ND/2217535)

Comment: Your solution would work, but I'd still have to get multiple pieces plus the bus bar, so I'm again nearing the cost of the $10 block that I already pictured in my original question (ok, maybe not as expensive.. :) ).  I already have ferrules and a proper crimper and will definitely go that route once I rewire.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to use crimp terminals (ring or fork) on the wires, rather than just putting the bare wires under the screws. See http://www.parts-express.com/cat/solderless-crimp-terminals/435 , for example.

There are jumper things for use with the barrier terminal strips you show, that can bridge adjacent terminals.

Comment: Those usually pull out with small wires like the ones in my panel.  However, I've kinda cheated before by folding the exposed wire back on itself to get a "thicker" wire.  But then with four connections on each terminal, ring / fork lugs are pretty useless because of the stackup.